# CountVectorizer(analyzer='char_wb') not working as expected

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use scikit-learn's `CountVectorizer` to count character 2-grams, ignoring spaces. In the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) it mentions the parameter `analyzer` which states

> Whether the feature should be made of word or character n-grams.
>   Option ‘char_wb’ creates character n-grams only from text inside word
>   boundaries.

However, "char_wb" doesn't appear to work as I expected.  For example:

```
corpus = [
    "The blue dog Blue",
    "Green the green cat",
    "The green mouse",
]

# CountVectorizer character 2-grams with word boundaries
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer='char_wb', ngram_range=(2, 2), min_df=1) 
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
vectorizer.get_feature_names()
[' b',
 ' c',
 ' d',
 ' g',
 ' m',
 ' t',
 'at',
 'bl',
 'ca', ....
```

Notice the examples like ' b' which include a space.  What gives?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is a longstanding inaccuracy in the documentation, which you are welcome to help fix. It would be more correct to say that:

> Option ‘char_wb’ creates character n-grams, but does not generate n-grams that cross word boundaries.

The change appears to have been made in [this commit](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/commit/e83fe8bf9a3bf6f538e8ad5fcba6812cf141feea) to ensure that; see the contributor's [comment](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/995#issuecomment-7469532). It looks particularly awkward when comparing the bigrams output to that of `analyzer='char'`, but when you increase to trigrams you will see that whitespace can begin or end an n-gram but cannot be in the middle. This helps to signify the word-initial or word-final nature of a feature without capturing noisy cross-word character n-grams. It also ensures that, unlike prior to that commit, all extracted n-grams have the same length!